# javascript/jquery: quick way to retrieve numeric from length attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have attributes which denotes "5 px", "8px" "6em" and possible some others which I currently cannot think of right now.
I'm interested in only the numeric value (ie 5, 8 or 6.) I know i can do some regex but I'm wondering is there a short, documented, cross browser and readable jquery / javascript function out there which already provides this?

regards,
Jeroen.

PS not sure if the wording in the title is correct please advice for alternatives.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? Where do these values come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`parseInt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) function:

```
var str = '5px';
alert(parseInt(str, 10));   // 5
```

Note that second argument of `10` represents base 10 there.

Comment: It is best (although often unnecessary) to call it: alert(parseInt(str),10). The 10 specifies that string you are parsing should be retuned from the decimal system (not hex or octal). I believe parseInt will also remove decimal places. So '22.5em' will return as '22'

Comment: and to catch NaN's and default to zero: myInt = parseInt(myStr,10).isNan() ? 0 : parseInt(myStr,10) ??

Comment: @lnrbob: For floats, you need to use `parseFloat`, not `parseInt`.

Comment: @jerry: You don't need to do conversion *again* by doing `myInt = parseInt(myStr,10).isNan() ? 0 : parseInt(myStr,10)`.

Comment: yup, I should have mentioned that. Its worth mentioning when dealing with ems :)

Answer (score 1):

In case they ever come back as `08px`, (leading zero), use the radix of `10`. Otherwise `parseint()` thinks your number is in octal.

```
var value = parseInt(str, 10);
```

It is probably never going to happen being returned from jQuery as a CSS property value, but a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of parseInt/parseFloat (see the other answers) is probably your best bet, but just for kicks (and if you want to make your code completely unreadable), you can always use a Regex with extra cheese:

```
+(str.match(/(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)||[,0])[1]
```

The + operator converts the result to a Number, `||[,0]` provides a default array if there's no number in `str`. `[,0]` might not work in all browsers, but `[0,0]` will.

:)